# tkz-fct produces no plots, why?

Tags: tkz-collection

`tkz-fct` produces no plots, for instance I copied the following code from the manual:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{tikz}%
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \tkzInit[xmax=100,xstep=10,
    ymax=1000000, ystep=100000]
    \tkzAxeX[right] \tkzAxeY[above]
    \tkzGrid \tkzFct[color=red,
    domain=0:100]{\x**3}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

This results in the following picture:

[image]

`gnuplot --version` gives:

> gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 2

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: To complete my answer, you can search gnuplot in you system to verify if gnuplot works correctly. Then you need to use pgf 2.1 with tkz-base, fct etc. and the option "--shell-escape" is necessary to allow the execution of Gnuplot. There are several answers about this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works:

[image]

You need to read your `.log` file to verify two things:

1. the path for `gnuplot`. If the path is fine then you must find a line like `gnuplot` executed or something like that
2. if in your `.log` file, you have something like

   > file.table not found,

   then you need to use the option `--shell-escape` or `write18` in your script for the compilation.

The problem is the same with `pgfplots` or another package that uses `gnuplot`.