# tkz-fct produces no plot

Tags: overleaf, tkz-fct

I've read some other answers all with similar problem. For example, at [tkz-fct produces no plots, why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/tkz-fct-produces-no-plots-why) some solution is given: "then you need to use the option --shell-escape or write18 in your script for the compilation".

Is it possible to apply this solution at Overleaf? I'm probably just asking this because I never had to use this kind of code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tikz,tikz-layers}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]

\tkzInit[xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-10,ymax=10]

\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY[>=latex]
\tkzFct[domain=-10:10,samples=1000,draw=red]{x}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And I receive at the log: `Package pgf Warning: Plot data file 'output.tkzfonct.table' not found. on input line 17.`

Comment: Also feel free to suggest a better title for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your project a file named `latexmkrc` with the following content:

```perl
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O %S --shell-escape';
$pdf_mode = 1;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
```

and recompile.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work in that file. So I tried to create another project and it worked normally.